# How do you reduce $H\left(e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)$ further according to a textbook solution

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, z-transform, proof

I want to know how I could get from the first line to the second. I've been trying to figure it out for a while with no luck. Thank you in advance!

\begin{align}
H\left(e^{j0.5\pi}\right) &= \frac{1 - e^{-j0.5\pi}}{1 - 0.25e^{-j\pi}}\\
&=1.13e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align}

Comment: You need to review your complex arithmetic.  Like *need*.  Because it'll come up later.  It needs to be almost as automatic as calculating 3/4.

Comment: Do you have any reference material to help re-familiarize myself with it?

Comment: Oh man, it's been so long.  I can tell you what room I was in (since torn down, it was Portland State University, in the building that looked like an inside-out shower stall), but not which class.

Comment: A web search on complex arithmetic coughed up a bunch of hits.  If you're a video person, I'd suggest the Khan acadamy one, just by their reputation.

Comment: I recently came back from a year and a half long internship and forgot almost everything. So things have become a game of catch-up. I'll do my best to review all the material, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got misled a bit in my initial reasoning. So, back to it.

If we have Equation $(1)$ here below
\begin{align}
H\left(e^{j0.5\pi}\right) &= \frac{1 - e^{-j0.5\pi}}{1 - 0.25e^{-j\pi}}\\
&= \frac{1 - e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}}{1 - \frac 14e^{-j\pi}}\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
And we know that $e^{j\theta} = \cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta)$. With this we have that
\begin{align}
e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}} &= -j\\
e^{-j\pi} &= -1\\
e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}} &= \frac{\sqrt2}{2} + j\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\\
\end{align}
Equation $(1)$ then becomes
\begin{align}
H\left(e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}\right) &= \frac 45\cdot \left(1 + j\right)\\
&=\frac 45\cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}{2} + j\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
&= \underbrace{\frac 45\cdot \sqrt{2}}_{\approx 1.13}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + j\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}_{e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}} \equiv 1.13\cdot e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}\\
\end{align}

Comment: $e^{-j\pi}=1$${}$?

Comment: Well spotted, my bad, let me fix that.

Comment: But then it turns out that the original solution is correct, i.e., the magnitude is indeed $1.13$.

Comment: Back online, thanks for the sharp eye on it.

Comment: Hey, thanks Gilles. Your and ZR Han's answer is helping me understand this a bit more. My class is challenging and I'm mainly using the textbook to learn the material.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: @Gilles: Sure, +1.

Answer (score 1):

By plotting the unit circle you will find that $1-e^{-j\pi/2} = \sqrt{2}e^{j\pi/4}$.
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still having some trouble understanding how you got there, do you mind showing me your complete steps? I'm truly sorry to ask this of you.

Comment: @nyxlotus Complex numbers behave just like vectors and follow the parallelogram law of vector addition. Here's a reference for you [What Are Complex Numbers?](https://nrich.maths.org/2432)

Comment: Thank you I'll do my best to review this infromation